# “ Expression denotes a `variable', where a `method group' was expected “ what does this mean?

Tags: c#, methods

I am learning c# as a beginner and making a program that gives the user a random number from a dice until it gets a six.
Here is my complete code:

```
using System;

class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
        Random numberGen = new Random();

        int roll = 0;
        int attempts = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the die");

        while (roll != 6) {
            Console.ReadKey();

            roll = numberGen(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("You rolled " + roll);
            attempts++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attempts + " to roll a six");
        Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I debug it?

Comment: `numberGen(1, 7)` should be `numberGen.Next(1, 7)`. Refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) for more. Side note: If you want the user to "press enter", use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.ReadKey()`. The latter will accept _any_ keystroke, not just the Enter key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```cs
roll = numberGen(1, 7);
```

The only time you can use `variable(...)` syntax is when `variable` is a typed delegate (in which case the compiler interprets it as `variable.Invoke(...)`). In all other cases, it is expected that you access some method/property/field/indexer/event *via* the variable, using one of `variable.Foo(...)`, `variable.Foo` or `variable[index]` (or `->` in place of `.` if `variable` is an unmanaged pointer).

In this case, you want:

```cs
roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have created a variable named - 'numberGen'.
Since its a variable of class 'Random', you need to call a method of this class using this variable like -

```
numberGen.Next(1,7);
```

Here 'Next' is a method of class Random, which takes 2 parameters, min value and max value.

The error you were getting was because you were using the variable as a method.

Answer (score 0):

The deafult approach to generate random numbers in rangs:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.Next(1, 10);
```

In your case hust update the variable

```
roll = numberGen(1, 7);
```

to:

```
roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
```

Random - it's a class.
Next - it's a method.

- More about **Classes** in C# [here](http://-%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)
- More about **Methods** in C# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)
- More about **Random** class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0)